# What is the lifetime of propane at standard conditions transitioning from an excited rotational state back to ground state?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, excited-states

I am a retired microwave engineer (88 yrs old) and have not had the opportunity to study or learn anything about quantum physics. I designed and built radars for the military.

We found a claim that stated you could find oil and gas seeps by pumping escaping gas molecules at a band resonant frequency and raise the energy level of that population. The lifetime in the excited state was reported to be very short and when it collapses some molecules will not return to their ground state leaving an energy level according to Planck’s law.

$$∆E = hf$$

This will be a different frequency band from the transmit frequency, so you can tune the receiver to this frequency and the ground clutter is eliminated. In other words, use it like a transponder and any targets displayed on the radar screen at the offset frequency would be escaping hydrocarbon gasses.

We wanted to verify the lifetime and collision rate, but lacked the knowledge to calculate the parameters. Pressed for time we went to the field to test the claim. No radiation could ever be detected at the offset frequency.

Was the $∆E$ lost in heat from collisions?

After all those years we still wonder about it. All assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Propane has $C_{2v}$ symmetry and lacks a permanent electric dipole (almost: it has been determined to be 0.083 D), so a purely rotational transition is less likely than a vibro-rotational one. That said, you may or may not have had the power to resolve the signal if you were doing this with, say, GPR in the Permian Basin. Any more details about the geology? That energy could very well have dissipated into the ground long before your receiver could have picked up the signal unless I am misunderstanding and you were looking at gas in the atmosphere at or near ground level.

Comment: Thanks Todd for the response. 
Yes, we  were looking for gas in the atmosphere from  ground level and above in a 12 degree radar elevation beam width. The radar was mounted on top of a Ford Bronco. Ground truth of the seep was measured by a Texas Instrument’s Geophysical Exploration Department field laboratory truck on a 10 foot grid from gas samples collected in 3 feet deep holes. This technique is accepted and used by the oil industry to compliment other exploration tools like seismic.